# Does iCloud password extension for Chrome work?

Tags: password, google-chrome

I have a couple of sites that I connect to on Chrome on my Mac and when I go to the logon screen, I get the following pop-up:
Enable Password AutoFIll
Click the toolbar button to enable the
iCloud Passwords extension for Chrome.

I go to the Chrome settings and see iCloud password extension is enabled.
Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to go into Chrome settings, just open the extension itself and enter a verification code to make sure it's you, and to link it to your device.

To do this, click the puzzle icon in the Chrome toolbar. Then click on the iCloud Passwords extension (to "open" it). A pop-up similar to the one below should appear on one of your devices (a trusted device - see [Get sent a verification code and sign in with two-factor authentication](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204974) for details) with a verification code, which you can enter in the appropriate field.

[image: Screenshot of the Chrome iCloud Password extension at first opening asking for a verification code and a popup from the system giving that verification code]

You should now be able to use iCloud Passwords on Chrome.

Comment: I never would have guessed to do that.   It's funny when I have to enter codes on my Mac when they show up on my Mac for me to copy them.